# Real logout BaseGameActivity

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have an `BaseGameActivity` in which the user should get the possibility to really logout. Calling `signOut();` is not enough since the next time the user starts the activity he automatically gets signed in again. But I want the activity to forget all account information such that when the user starts the activity again the activity asks him for his account information and needs the user's permission like the very first time. How is such a logout possible?

Comment: any solution for full logout ?

Answer (score 2):

I would like the user to either be signed in every time if they were signed in on the previous app use or not automatically signed in if they explicitly signed out.

In the `GameHelper.java` `onStart()` method there is a check on whether or not to auto sign in. It looks like this

```
if (mConnectOnStart)
{
    //Call connect and such
}
```

You should also have a Sign In and a Sign Out button. Whenever the user taps on of the sign in or sign out button set a flag in shared preferences on whether to auto connect. Whenever the user taps the sign in button set this boolean to `true`. When they hit the sign out button set it to `false`. There is a `setConnectOnStart(boolean connectOnStart)` that you can call on your app initializiation with the SharedPreference value you saved.

Now, instead of signing in even if the user signed out last time, it will not attempt the sign in again until they hit the sign in button (and you set the `boolean` preference). You can also set the `DEFAULT_MAX_SIGN_IN_ATTEMPTS` to whatever you want so the user doesn't get prompted too many times after install.

See the last section of these [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin).